# identify a column by its name for a specified value for each row, r

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, data-manipulation, r-raster

G'day everyone,

I have a data.frame with many columns of data, however, for each row I am only interested in a subset of these columns. I would like to use another specific value to identify the column I am interested in. I will then take the mean of the column of interest and the 5 previous columns.

My data.frame includes point location, month of collection and values extracted from a set of monthly rasters over 1996-2012 for each point. For each point I am interested in a six month average prior to the collection date, eg. if I recorded a variable in 200106 (06/2001) I want the average of the rasters from 200101-200106.

Date of collection values are coded the same as the column names that corresponds to values extracted for the same month.

Is there a way to identify the column I am interested in given the collection date I have?

My data.frame looks like:

```
    df <- data.frame(lat = c(-34, -34.5, -35, -35.5, -36, -36.5, -37),
                     lon = c(144, 144.5, 145, 145.5, 146, 146.5, 147),
                     dt = c('x200106', 'x200107', 'x200108', 'x200109', 'x200110', 'x200111', 'x200112'),
                     x200101 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                     x200102 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
                     x200103 = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5),
                     x200104 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
                     x200105 = c(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5),
                     x200106 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7),
                     x200107 = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27),
                     x200108 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70),
                     x200109 = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5),
                     x200110 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
                     x200111 = c(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.5, 16.5, 17.5),
                     x200112 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7))
```

Given dt (date) can I get a six month average of the corresponding columns?

I have no idea how to proceed, I imagine a data transformation of some kind but don't know where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks lots!

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: are the dates supposed to in row and column?

Comment: @6pool yes they are. The dt column is the date that the data point was collected. The columns with dates as col.names correspond to the raster file that that columns values were extracted from. I want to use my dt value to find the corresponding raster data contained in row 'dt'. It is confusing and I am bad at explaining what I am trying to do, I apologise for that.

Comment: Adam, does my answer below not do what you ask?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing you want to do is reshape your data so that it is in long format, and convert the dates so that you can perform arithmetic on them.  This is what we do here:

```
library(reshape2)
df.mlt <- melt(df, id.vars=c("lat", "lon", "dt"))
df.mlt[c("dt", "variable")] <- lapply(df.mlt[c("dt", "variable")], function(x) as.Date(paste0(x, "01"), format="x%Y%m%d"))
library(data.table)
data.table(df.mlt)[(dt - variable) %between% c(0, 190), mean(value), by=list(lat, lon, dt)]
```

Look at `df.mlt` to see what I mean by long format (basically, the columns become rows). The second command just converts the two columns `dt`, and `variable` (`variable` holds the names of what used to be columns before the melt) into date format.  Finally, I use `data.table` to select the appropriate rows (date difference must be less than 190, which I take to be a proxy for six months assuming your data is monthly this should be safe) and to compute statistics on row groups (you could also use `dplyr` or other "split/apply/combine" style techniques).  This produces:

```
     lat   lon         dt        V1
1: -34.0 144.0 2001-06-01  6.016667
2: -34.5 144.5 2001-07-01 10.314286
3: -35.0 145.0 2001-08-01 16.328571
4: -35.5 145.5 2001-09-01 14.700000
5: -36.0 146.0 2001-10-01 18.214286
6: -36.5 146.5 2001-11-01 20.442857
7: -37.0 147.0 2001-12-01 20.342857
```

update: apparently I can't count: these are averages of six months, as per your question.

Comment: Thanks BrodieG, that works exactly how I want. It works really well with my data... although I am still trying to get my head around the data.table stuff. This will definitely come in handy with stuff I will be doing in the future as well. Cheers